# Is there a way to launch a Jenkins node inside a scripted pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, amazon-ec2

This is the problem I'm trying to solve:

I have an EC2 instance which is registered as a Jenkins node. However, the EC2 instance is started/stopped if needed in a job. I need to be able to launch the agent after I start the instance. Pipeline should be like this:

1. start instance (via AWS CLI in build step)
2. start jenkins agent on instance
3. perform build steps on instance
4. stop instance (via AWS CLI in build step)

I know there is a plugin which will allow you to spin up instances from AMIs on demand, but that's not my use-case. I just need a way within the pipeline to tell jenkins "this node is now reachable, launch the agent on the node".

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [jclouds](https://plugins.jenkins.io/jclouds-jenkins/) plugin has a pretty good documentation.

You must go to Dashboard > Manage Jenkins > nodes & Clouds > clouds.
You will need to "cook" your own jenkins agent image and use it or use a init script and a standard ami image.

example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
yum -y install https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
yum install git yum-utils zip unzip jq -y
yum -y install java-11-openjdk java-11-openjdk-devel -y....
```

To use the agent you refer on the label in the pipeline:

```
stages {
  stage('Build') {
    agent { label 'my-aws-dynamic-agent-01' }
    steps{....}
  }
}
```

Comment: As I said in my post, I don't really want to use one of the EC2 AMI launcher plugins, since they seem to be hit-or-miss, but I'll give this a shot and report back!